# MySql Insert Into 2 Different Tables Using Left Join

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database, left-join

I'm trying to update the timestamp column in TABLE A, when a new record is created in TABLE B for the matching record. It is a relational database where records link. When a new record is created in TABLE B, it references an already established record in TABLE A. You can't create a new record in B without linking to record in A.

TABLE A: id, name, date, address, timestamp

TABLE B: id, a_id, agent, comment

WHERE b.a_id = a.id

I've been through these forums and seem to get conflicting answers. What is the sql query I would use to make this work? Do I need to use some type of JOIN? Here's where I'm at:

```
INSERT INTO b ( a_id, agent, comment)
     VALUES ( 1008, 'TEST', 'Hello world!');
INSERT INTO a (timestamp)
     VALUES ((SELECT id FROM b WHERE b.a_id = a.id), current_timestamp);
```

Comment: you can't use `joins` to update multiple tables in a single query. You might look into `triggers` though if I understand correctly https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @ramraider of course you can

Comment: @cam308 see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You don't mean a query, you mean an update command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you want to accomplish. Are you trying to update the timestamp in the row in `a` that has a_id 1008?

```
INSERT INTO b (a_id, agent, comment)
     VALUES (1008, 'TEST', 'Hello world!');

UPDATE a SET timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = 1008;
```

I would do it exactly as I show above. Do the INSERT to `b`, then UPDATE `a`.

If you want it to happen automatically, you can use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER b_ins AFTER INSERT ON b
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE a SET timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = NEW.a_id;
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! Create a new record in B, while updating the timestamp in A that corresponds to that id.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you